# .bat file interaction with java or C#.net GUI application

Tags: c#, netbeans, batch-file, command-prompt

How to interact .bat file with java or C#.net GUI application? Here is part of my .bat code.

`:Valid`

`echo Enter student id:`

`set/p "pass=>"`

`if NOT %pass%== UserStudentId goto FAIL`

When I run the .bat file it will ask  `Enter student id:` in command prompt, then validate the student id and do some process. 
I want to pass this input from java or C#.net IDE to .bat file and continue the process. In here User will never deal with command prompt. 
If there is any output from .bat , it will show in java or .net IDE also.

I wonder if it is possible since I'm new to this. TX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start a process from Java or C# you can get console input and output of that process as streams. You then can simply write into the process' input stream.

It *might* be, though, that the batch file won't actually like that since `cmd` might look for actual interactive input with `set /p` (e.g., it fails with file redirection, if I remember correctly). A better method, if you control the batch file itself, would be the following:

```
if defined pass goto SkipInput
set /p pass=Enter student ID:
:SkipInput
```

which will use an environment variable if present and only ask the user if it isn't already set. This is much more automation-friendly, since you can just set the environment variable in the calling process and have it inherited for every process you spawn. And no hassle with emulating input as well.